# Setting descendant property to the parent ID with AutoFixture

Tags: autofixture

My Customer object has a CustomerNote property. When AutoFixture creates my Customer, it also creates a CustomerNote. My CustomerNote has a property (Guid) of the CustomerId.

Without expliciting setting a variable (var cId = Guid.New //and then passing that in at Customer creation), can set my CustomerNote.CustomerId to 'this' Customer?

NB: I'm using Autofixture to seed an EF db

```
var Biller = _Fixture.Create<Biller>();
var Customer = _Fixture.Build<Customer>().With(x => x.Biller, Biller)
                                                    .With(x => x.BillerId, Biller.Id)
                                                    .Create();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use value of a parent property when creating a complex child in AutoFixture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319984/use-value-of-a-parent-property-when-creating-a-complex-child-in-autofixture)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29027945/126014

Comment: See also: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/242