# Circular reference object creation throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, autofixture

I'm trying to create a fake of a DbSet that represents the fact table in a star schema database. Here's a simplified example where AutoFixture throws a NullReferenceException

```
public class FctAssumption
{
    public virtual DimAssumption DimAssumption { get; set; }
}

public class DimAssumption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FctAssumption> FctAssumptions { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var fake = fixture.Build<FctAssumption>()
            .Without(x => x.DimAssumption.FctAssumptions)
            .Create();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create a FctAssumption using AutoFixture?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7319984/126014

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I guess I'm going to remove the FctAssumptions property on all of the dimension table classes to avoid the circular references then.

Comment: Also, I thoroughly enjoyed Dependency Injection in .NET and recommend it to all my developer friends/coworkers!